# ZF3 - AbstractTranslatorHelper and sprintf

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have a simple view helper "Header" with two parameters `title` and `subtitle`. My helper extends the AbstractTranslatorHelper for translating the two strings.

Now I have the case, that I have to set some variables in the given string. Normally I would do this with `sprintf($this->translate('My string with the variable %s', 'test')`. But how can I set the string and the variables in my helper, to handle the translation in it. Or do I really have to translate it before I set it?

At the moment I do it that way, but I don't really like it...

```
$this->header(sprintf($this->translate('title with variable %s'), 'test'), 'subtitle')
```

Comment: any feedback to make?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I could not answer because I was on the road. Your solution works fine!

Comment: No problem i'm just glad it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
$this->header('title with variable %s', 'subtitle')->setTitleVariables([$variables])->setSubtitleVariables([$subVars]);
```

where your main code for this to work is :

```
class HeaderHelper extends AbstractTranslatorHelper
{
    public function __invoke($title, $subtitle)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->subtitle = $subtitle;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setTitleVariables(array $variables)
    {
        $this->title = $this->translate(vsprintf($this->title, $variables));
        return $this;
    }

    public function setSubtitleVariables( array $variables)
    {
        $this->subtitle = $this->translate(vsprintf($this->subtitle, $variables));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

With this code by calling either `setTitleVariables` or `setSubtitleVariables` you can pass variable for those two strings

Then, up to you with your populated helper to choose how to render those strings.

But I suggest you this method :

```
 public function render()
    {
        return "<h1>" . $this->title . "</h1>" . "<h3>" . $this->subtitle . "</h3>";
    }
```

Of course you can design this by using a `.phtml` file or anything you want as long as you render a string
and then the code below :

```
$this->header('title with variable %s', 'subtitle')->setTitleVariables([$variables])->render();
```

Will do the full thing !